# How to split() string with double square brackets in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change this

`let str = "Tom left from [[his]] home";`

to

`array = ["Tom left from ", "[[his]]", " home"];`

I have tried like this

```
array = []; c = 0;
array = str.split(/([[[]]])/).filter(Boolean).forEach(e => 
e == '[[' ? c++ : e == ']]' ? c-- : c > 0 ? array.push('[[' + e + ']]') : array.push(e) 
); 

console.log(array)
```

Comment: what you want and the usage of split is not clear to me? do you want to use replace maybe? replace(/(.*)([[.*]])(.*)/, $1 + '::' + $2 + '::' + $3), after edit { to [ ignore replace ^^

Comment: You should favor readability over shortness. Nesting ternary operators is a big no-no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
str.split(/(\[\[.+?\]\])/).filter(Boolean)
```

and thats it, no need some extra execution

PS About your code:

1) Square brackets inside regular expression needs backslashes in front of them since they are parts of expressions syntax

2) forEach just iterates over elements, it returns undefined, so your code is totally meaningless when you assign value to array, so whatever you made with variable array, you annigilated, in such case use map function, which creates a new array, transforming vaues of existing

```
array = str.split(/whatever/).filter(Boolean).map(e => 
e == '[[' ? c++ : e == ']]' ? c-- : c > 0 ? '[[' + e + ']]' : e 
);
```

Comment: @DhananjaiPai, i didnt add backskash to square brackets, now it should work

Comment: @DhananjaiPai, shame on Me, but i dont remember how to make it lazy

Comment: `.split(/(\[\[.+?\]\])/)`

Comment: @DhananjaiPai, yes, like this is perfect, i edited according it

Comment: @carte, please read my update, where i pointed to some flaws in your code, it can be helpful for you